# Removing HTML tags using JQuery from content pulled using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags

So I am pulling content from a Discussion List in Sharepoint and dropping it in RTE text area on a new form. It all works well except that it puts all the content plus all the html tags in the text area and all I want is the text.

How can I remove the html tags without messing up the styling in the text area.

Answer (score 3):

```
var html = '<div class="blue">This is blue text</div>';
$(html).text(); //will strip the html tags and return only the text.
```

Comment: function CopyBodyToDescription(contentbody) {
 
  
  var systemDescriptionRTETextArea = $("textarea[Title='Description']");
  //alert($(systemDescriptionRTETextArea).html());
  $(systemDescriptionRTETextArea).text(contentbody);
  //alert($(systemDescriptionRTETextArea).text());
  
}//  End Function

Comment: Thats my code to put the content into the RTE would would I implement your code

Answer (score 0):

A html textarea does not recognize html tags. You would need a javascript plugin to do that.